# VBA Macro that Create Macro in Active Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I found a way to highlight row when cell is selected. I would like to use it in every excel file I open but there is a problem. There are two steps. First, I have to create conditional formatting. Second, create a simple macro in the active sheet, not a normal module or personal.

My idea is that I create a personal macro that will do the first step (cond. form.) and then somehow create **THE macro** in the active sheet. But I don't know how.

Is it even possible?

This is the code I need to put into active sheeet module.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   Target.Calculate
End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [application-level events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-application-level-event-handler)

Comment: Creating a macro by a macro is a challenge. It is easier to copy macro's. Once I created a macro that copied macro's from one Word-document to another. I only noticed that the virus scanner didn't like it, since it is virus-like functionality. If you cannot disable the virus scanner, than I don't think it is possible.

Comment: @ffonz I cannot disable it.

Comment: Maybe a personal macro workbook is what you want? See [here](https://trumpexcel.com/personal-macro-workbook/).

Comment: @ffonz I will use a personal macro for the first part, but the following code must be in sheet module otherwise it's not working.

Comment: The last thing I can come up with is a template. You can create an Excel template and place this macro in. But that works only for newly created sheets from that template, not for existing workbooks.

Comment: I don't have ready access to files in which I've done it, but it is possible to copy code between workbooks via VBA. I had one particular worksheet that effectively lobotomized itself on opening, and then pulled in new/updated code from a network location. I wish I could help more, but if you do some digging on "Trust access to the VBA project object model" you should be able to find an answer.